# error visual studio 2015 cordova Android Package: extra-android-support

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PWgT.png)whenever I check the dependencies of " cordova " tells me that this package is missing "extra -android -support " . I attach the screen of tools and extras that I installed dall'android sdk manager.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had to click the checkbox to Show Obsolete packages and then clicked the Updates link (blue text).

This selected **Android Support Library** in the Extras folder.

(edit: I see that this is mentioned in the comments above, but I didn't notice that so I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone else)

Comment: It appears this no longer shows up when Obsolete is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Android SDK Tools 25.1.7 component. You should download it directly from the Android SDK manager you have open there.

Also, did you download Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova recently? Did you install the Android tools with VS?

If so, then you can't update the Android SDK where it is now Program Files (x86). What would be easiest is downloading your own copy of Android Studio, add all the components you have today plus the Android SDK Tools, and link VS to that in Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Overriding Environment Variables.

Comment: @ljzhong  I'm having the same problem.  I verified with SDK Manager that I have `Android SDK Tools` 25.1.7 installed.  I don't want to download the Android Studio.  What do I need to change in Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Overriding Environment Variables?  ADT_HOME?

Thank you

Comment: @DeanB_Develop, open the SDK tools manager again, in the bottom "Extras" dropdown, select the following 2 packages: Android Support Repository, Android Support Library.

Comment: @lizhong Thanks for the help!  I had installed `Android Support Repository` using the Android SDK Manager. I didn't see a `Android Support Library` in Extras until I selected show > `Obsolete`.  

`Dependency Checker` does not find any missing or misconfigured components.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Studio 3... there is no Extras in it. 
So you have to download Support Lib (about 1mb), unzip 
and put it in the [ADT_HOME]\extras\android.